# How to retrive customer info or payment intent in succes page stripe php slim

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments, slim

hi i want to take amount, customer name and email on my success page but I am struggling to do.

this is my PHP server side codes which send request to stripe.

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Stripe\Stripe;




require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

require './config.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
    return $next($request, $response);
});

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  return $response->write(file_get_contents(getenv('STATIC_DIR') . './grid-test.html','/index-copy.html'));
});

$app->post('/checkout_sessions', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app)  {
  $params = json_decode($request->getBody());
  $payment_method_types = [
    'usd' => ['card'],
    'eur' => ['card'],
    'cad' => ['card']
  ];
  $products = [
    'Private' => 'prod_435646574',
  ];

  $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/?cancel=true',
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'payment_intent_data' => [
      'metadata' => [
        'package' => $params->package,
        'date' => $params->datepicker,
        'no of adults' => $params->adults,
        'no of children' => $params->children,
        'occupancy' => $params->occupancy,
        'tour' => $params->tour,
        'location' => $params->location,
      ]
    ],
    'metadata' => [
      'package' => $params->package,
      'date' => $params->datepicker,
      'no of adults' => $params->adults,
      'no of children' => $params->children,
      'occupancy' => $params->occupancy,
      'tour' => $params->tour,
      'location' => $params->location,
    ],
    'submit_type' => 'donate',
    'line_items' => [[
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'aed',
        'product' => $products[$params->package],
        'unit_amount' => $params->amount,
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'phone_number_collection' => [
      'enabled' => true,
    ],
    
  ]);

  return $response->withJson([
    'id' => $session->id
  ]);
});




$app->run();
```

this is my success page which I am not able to get checkout session or payment intent details

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var sessionId = params.get('id');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount')

fetch('/get-session?id=' + sessionId)
.then((Response) => Response.json())
.then((session) => {
    amount.innerText = session.payment_intent.amount;
    
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Thank You For Order</title>
    

</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="checkout">
      <div id="payment-form">
        <h1>Success!</h1>

        <p>
        Thanks so much for donating <strong id="amount"></strong> to 

        </p>

        <a href="/">Donate More?!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

hi i want to take amount, customer name and email on my success page but I am struggling to do.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what your `fetch('/get-session?id=' + sessionId)` call would do since you don’t have any API route configured for that in your `Slim` app code you shared. But basically what you want to do in that endpoint is to retrieve the Checkout Session like so

```
$session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  'cs_xxxxx',
  [['expand' => ['payment_intent', 'customer']]
);
return $response->withJson($session);
```

which would give you access to `session.payment_intent.amount` or you could use `session.amount_total`.

For the customer name and email you could access those via the Customer object `session.customer.name` and `session.customer.email`.

> P.S.: It’s not ideal to send the whole Checkout Session object to the frontend. Instead you could send a JSON with the few details that you need and adjust your frontend accordingly.

**EDIT:**

As per your comment please find the changes that I would recommend doing.

```
//Changes on the backend
return $response->withJson([[
  //you could add any other info you'd like to send to the frontend
  'amount' => $session->payment_intent->amount,
  'email' => $session->customer->email,
  'name' => $session->customer->name
]]);

//Changes on the frontend
fetch('/get-session?id=' + sessionId)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((session) => {
    amount.innerText = session.amount;
    //you could also use session.email and session.name
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: can you show example of JSON in my case how would I do it and on front end how to retrieve JSON

Comment: just one example like how will json send send and how does success page collect do we use DOM in java

Comment: I hope my edit gives you more context